# working with image from imagecreatefromstring PHP

Tags: php, iphone, image, upload

So i have an iphone app that that uploads an image to my webserver and i looked around and people seem to be doing something like

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

I looked at the php docs, but i still don't understand what the header() does; does it convert the image into whatever format i want?

And for the imagepng(), where is the image outputted to? memory? is that why i need the imagedestroy()?

and where would i put in

```
move_uploaded_file()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header is purely for the server to let the browser know "Oh hey this is a png image please render it so"

`imagepng` encodes it into the png format and "prints" to the output

`imagedestroy` frees the memory taken by the image resource.

If you need to force extension  you can use mod_rewrite

Here's a sample couple lines from my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule images/000000/00FF00/newmyinfo.jpg images/newmyinfo.php?bgcolor=000000&color=00ff00  [L]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! that cleared up alot of my questions.  So is there a way to get the extension and path of my newly created resource so that i can save it into my image server? I want to use toe move_uploaded_file($image,$final_path) but the $image needs to be a string

Comment: Most of it is done through $_FILES[].  Some docs to check out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php
 and  http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: @Andrew: Maybe I misunderstood.  You can use `imagepng($imgresource, $path)` to output the `$imgresource` to the `$path` you want

Answer (score 2):

This code is intended to return as output an image - you could use it as a valid `src` for an image tag. That is, you could do this:

`<img src="thatfile.php?something=1" />`

The headers tell the browser that the data the server is going to send is an image (a PNG image, specifically).

In your example code, the file never actually gets written anywhere: the data stays in memory until the script ends, then it is simply "forgotten". `imagedestroy` frees up the memory and is good practice, but it really isn't necessary since the memory will be garbage collected after the request ends. If you want to preserve the image in a file, you'd have to use one of the related functions such as `imagepng`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php.  The only difference between writing the file or not in your example code is the lack of a second argument for `imagepng` - second argument would be the desired file path.

It would help to read through the docs on this entire subject to gain a firm grasp of how these functions work and what each does. There are plenty of demos on the doc pages that show this in action.

Answer (score 1):

This particular example gets the image uploaded through POST from the `$_FILES` array and simply outputs it back to the browser. The `header` is there to inform the browser that the content following is a PNG image.

Since you create an image from a string, it doesn't have "an extension". It's just an image *resource* at this point. You can create an actual file from it using `imagepng`, `imagejpeg` or any of the other methods to save an image resource to a file. You decide the *extension* (and file name) at that stage yourself.

E.g.:

```
imagepng($image, 'path/to/file.png');
```

---

> and where would i put in `move_uploaded_file()`?

You wouldn't, since you don't have an uploaded file, only a string.